# How can I handle a button click on Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I have a button in my main interface. I did a `ctl + drag` from the button in the storyboard to the `InterfaceController.m` I then put an `NSLog` in the resulting method. This is what the code looks like

```
#import "InterfaceController.h"


@interface InterfaceController()

@end


@implementation InterfaceController

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
     NSLog(@"awakeWithContext!");
    // Configure interface objects here.
}

- (IBAction)Alarm {
    NSLog(@"Alarm!");

}

- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];
     NSLog(@"willActivate!");
}

- (void)didDeactivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    [super didDeactivate];
     NSLog(@"didDeactivate!");
}

@end
```

I also took a screenshot with the logs appearing. No log occurs when a I press the Alarm button in the emulator.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I just followed the example in this video. 
"How to connect a WKInterfaceButton to an action in the code using Xcode" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuCuL-a608w

I added this to the header `- (IBAction)alarmPressed:(id)sender;`
I put this in the view controller

```
- (IBAction)alarmPressed:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"alarmPressed!");
}
```

I dragged the sent action select to the `Interface Controller` and selected `alarmPressed`. This still does not produce logs when pressed. Also traits includes "User Interaction Enabled"

Comment: When I followed the description at  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuCuL-a608w, it worked.

Comment: can you share the method by which you make it succeed? For some country doesn't have access to youtube...you know.

Comment: I was able to get it to work eventually but I don't recall how. Sorry. This post should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the watchKit doesn't support the :(id)sender argument. so your IBAction should just read

```
-(IBAction)alarmPressed{
    NSLog(@"alarmPressed!"):
}
```

also make sure that this dot is filled in. if it isn't that means you need to click on the hollow dot and drag it to your button.

[image: A Working outlet]